# How do I find the time complexity for the "Collect maximum coins" DP solution?

Tags: r, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

can any one help me to analysis this algorithm in details

Check the following link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collect-maximum-coins-before-hitting-a-dead-end/

there is two solutions for this problem the first one is exponential i think without DP, but the other one is O(R.C) with Dynamic programming and ***memoization***.

Where R is the number for rows for the 2D-Array & C the number of columns.

**I need to know how i can mathematically find this time complexity O(R.C) in details.**

Comment: I think your question should be posted in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

DP solution fills `RxCx2` table `dp`and every cell of `dp` might be visited not more that five times  - initial fill, calculation for this cell, and request from three directions (up, left, right).

So overall complexity is `O(R * C)`